# pyqt4 drawing arc from other py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Trying to draw arc and problem is I want to cal draw function form another py file and no luck so far (if draw function in main py file it is ok). I imported another py file but nothing happens. here is the code:
main.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore
import sys
from src.cPrg import cPrg
from PyQt4.Qt import QPen

class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):

    super(mainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.otherFile = cPrg()

    self.initUI()



def initUI(self):

    #self.exitBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit', self)
    #self.exitBtn.setGeometry(100,100,60,40)
    #self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.close_app)

    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.label.setText(self.otherFile.textas)
    self.label.setGeometry(100,140, 60, 40)

    self.otherFile.setGeometry(20,20, 20,20)
    self.otherFile.startA = 270
    self.otherFile.endA = -270


    #self.showFullScreen()
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 480)
    self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')

    self.show()

def close_app(self):
    sys.exit()



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and anotherfile.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
from PyQt4.Qt import QPen

class cPrg(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):

    super(cPrg, self).__init__()

    self.startA = 0
    self.endA = 0
    self.textas = 'bandom'

def paintEvent(self, e):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
    rect = e.rect

    r = QtCore.QRect(200,200,20,20)                            #<-- create rectangle
    size = r.size()                                            #<-- get rectangle size
    r.setSize(size*10)                                         #<-- set size
    startAngle = self.startA*16                                #<-- set start angle to draw arc
    endAngle = self.endA*16                                    #<-- set end arc angle

    painter.setPen(QPen(QtGui.QColor('#000000')))              #<-- arc color
    #painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.HorPattern)
    painter.drawArc(r, startAngle, endAngle)                   #<-- draw arc


    painter.end()
    super(cPrg,self).paintEvent(e)
```

What I doing wrong and how can I change line width?
Thank you

EDIT: all painting I made in main py file, here is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore
import sys
from src.cprg import cPrg
from src.cprogress import GaugeWidget
from PyQt4.Qt import QPen

class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):

    self.otherFile = cPrg()
    self.gauge = GaugeWidget()

    self.i = 0
    self.lineWidth = 3
    self._value = 0
    self.completed = 0

    super(mainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.setValue(.5)

    #self.showFullScreen()
    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 480)
    self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')

    self.show()

def close_app(self):
    sys.exit()

def setValue(self, val):
    val = float(min(max(val, 0), 1))
    self._value = -270 * val
    self.update()

def setLineWidth(self, lineWidth):
    self.lineWidth = lineWidth

def paintEvent(self, e):

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
    rect = e.rect

    outerRadius = min(self.width(),self.height())
    #arc line
    r = QtCore.QRect(20,20,outerRadius-10,outerRadius-10)                            #<-- create rectangle
    size = r.size()                                            #<-- get rectangle size
    r.setSize(size*.4)                                         #<-- set size
    startAngle = 270*16                                #<-- set start angle to draw arc
    endAngle = -270*16                                    #<-- set end arc angle

    painter.setPen(QPen(QtGui.QColor('#000000'), self.lineWidth))              #<-- arc color
    #painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.HorPattern)
    painter.drawArc(r, startAngle, endAngle)                   #<-- draw arc

    #arc prg
    painter.save()
    painter.setPen(QPen(QtGui.QColor('#ffffff'), 20))
    painter.drawArc(r, startAngle, self._value*16)
    painter.restore()

    painter.end()
    super(mainWindow,self).paintEvent(e)

def main():
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = mainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

this is my simple circular progress bar, now question is how can I place setValue, setlineWidth and paintEvent functions into separate py file and then just call by importing this file and class with these functions? I tried this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore
import sys
from src.cprg import cPrg              #<import progressbar
from src.cprogress import GaugeWidget
from PyQt4.Qt import QPen

class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):

    self.otherFile = cPrg()           #< imported progress bar
    self.gauge = GaugeWidget()

    self.i = 0
    self.lineWidth = 3
    self._value = 0
    self.completed = 0

    super(mainWindow, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.otherFile.setGeometry(10,10,100,100)   #<<<< progress bar size
    self.otherFile.setValue(0.5)                #< progress bar value
```

and this is not working.

Comment: What do you expect to get ?, your logic is very wrong.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to get draw in cPrg.py file and in main.py file just simple call cPrg and just setGeometry for size.

Comment: @eyllanesc  and why logic is wrong? I have example - have circular progress bar in separate file and I calling this progress bar in main file and it is working (paintEvent is in progress bar py file). I know I new to python and pyqt as well so want to know more about wrong logic in this case. thank you

Comment: It is always good to place what you want. Update your post with this request

Comment: @eyllanesc just updated my post.

Comment: Update my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line width with `QPen(color, line_width)`, `update()` redraw with paintEvent.

try with this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class cPrg:
    def __init__(self):
        self.linewidth = 0

    def setLineWidth(self, linewidth):
        self.linewidth = linewidth

    def drawArc(self, painter):
        painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
        r = QtCore.QRect(200,200,20,20)                            #<-- create rectangle
        size = r.size()                                            #<-- get rectangle size
        r.setSize(size*10)                                         #<-- set size
        startAngle = self.startA*16                                #<-- set start angle to draw arc
        endAngle = self.endA*16                                    #<-- set end arc angle
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('#000000'), self.linewidth))              #<-- arc color
        painter.drawArc(r, startAngle, endAngle)                   #<-- draw arc


class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.otherFile = cPrg()
        self.initUI()
        self.i = 0

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText(self.otherFile.textas)
        self.label.setGeometry(100,140, 60, 40)
        self.otherFile.startA = 270
        self.otherFile.endA = -270
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.changeLineWidth)
        timer.start(1000)

    def changeLineWidth(self):
        self.otherFile.setLineWidth(self.i)
        self.i += 1
        self.i %= 60
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.otherFile.drawArc(painter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = mainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want a circular progressbar, your must be override QProgressbar:

```
from math import ceil

from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qt, QtCore
import sys


class cPrg(QtGui.QProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(cPrg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.linewidth = 1

    def factor(self, value):
        a = 360 / (self.maximum() - self.minimum())
        b = -a / (self.maximum() - self.minimum())
        return a*value + b

    def setLineWidth(self, linewidth):
        self.linewidth = linewidth
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)
        r = self.rect()
        val = ceil(self.factor(self.value()))
        nr = QtCore.QRect(r.topLeft() + QtCore.QPoint(self.linewidth, self.linewidth),
                   QtCore.QSize(r.width()-2*self.linewidth, r.height()-2*self.linewidth))
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('#000000'), self.linewidth))
        painter.drawArc(nr, 0*16, val*16)


class mainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.otherFile = cPrg(self)
        self.otherFile.setMinimum(0)
        self.otherFile.setMaximum(360)
        self.otherFile.setValue(90)
        self.initUI()

        timerLW = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timerLW.timeout.connect(self.changeLW)
        timerLW.start(100)

        timerVal = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timerVal.timeout.connect(self.updateValue)
        timerVal.start(100)

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("test")
        self.label.setGeometry(200, 200, 60, 40)

        self.otherFile.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window Title')

    def changeLW(self):
        lw = (self.otherFile.linewidth + 1) % 20
        self.otherFile.setLineWidth(lw)

    def updateValue(self):
        self.otherFile.setValue(self.otherFile.value() + 1)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = mainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer this is working, but possible make like this al drawing make in cPrg.py file and in main.py file just call cPrg without redrawing?

Comment: thank you! where you been when I started looking for circular progress bar example? :) Now I want to learn do it by my self and my arc looks like (and acting like) progress bar just cant make size by setGeometry. Anyway thank you!

Comment: by the way can you tell me why I can set up my progress bar size bu setGeometry?

Comment: All the widget inherits from QWidget